# Change kernel version from command line

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, pxe

Is there a way to reboot with a different kernel version from the command line? 
I have Ubuntu PXE booted on a VM, and there is no graphical interface, but I need to downgrade the kernel (which is installed).

Comment: Are you asking how to reboot or how to install a new kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your grub configuration as necessary - if you want to use it for longer, and install the new grub setup then to disk(s).

This I believe will help you understand grub configuration:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Otherwise I think kexec may also help you.

Install kexec with:

```
sudo apt-get install kexec-tools
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain how the GRUB configuration would be edited and what edits are necessary. As it stands, this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to one-time reboot selection consider using `grub-reboot` command;
- If you want to set selection permanently use `grub-set-default` command.

Bot these commands require MENU-ITEM as parameter, for listing yours see:
[How to list GRUB's “menuentries” in command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line)

---

*But, you can always hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, to show Grub Menu, isn't it possible in your VM manager?*

Comment: Makes me think if there is easy way of listing every "menuentry", as greping `grub.cfg` doesn't seem like a good idea. Maybe new question is needed?

Comment: Question about listing menuentries: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line)