# GRUB refuses to reboot into a new kernal

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I found the menuentry/subentry that I wanted to use, as you can see here: https://gyazo.com/b73fa2308145caaed7959a95d71a4bc8

I then changed this in /etc/default/grub to this: GRUB_DEFAULT=1>0

I updated grub with: sudo update-grub

And then rebooted the system with: sudo reboot

It still loads into the same old kernal.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus#Submenu_Designation_Examples) the format is one of

- `GRUB_DEFAULT="Previous Linux versions>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-18-generic-pae"`
- `GRUB_DEFAULT="Previous Linux versions>0"`
- `GRUB_DEFAULT="2>0"`
- `GRUB_DEFAULT="2>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-18-generic-pae"`

Your screenshot instead shows

```
1>0 Ubuntu, with....
```

It lacks the `GRUB_DEFAULT=` part, the quotes `"…"`, and is a 
mixture of both numeric and textual item selection. Try

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>0"
```

Comment: I changed by GRUB_DEFAULT like you said, updated grub, and restarted the dedi server. It turned back on but was still the old kernal.

Comment: @GeorgeAshby Does it work when you manually select the new kernel?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot open the boot menu on system startup as I dont have the ability. I bought a dedicated server off of OVH.

Comment: Try using the textual version "Previous Linux Versions>Ubuntu" etc. It's much more straightforward IMHO.

Comment: Have you seen [How to list GRUB's “menuentries” in command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/599208/504066) It may help to figure out the correct item.