# grub-reboot: not seeing the Windows entry listed?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am trying to use `grub-reboot` to boot just once to Windows (following this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/285755/boot-to-windows-once-from-grub-then-back-to-ubuntu-on-next-boot)).

Strangely enough, using the auto-completion from `grub-reboot` (or `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`  from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line),) I only see Ubuntu entries, or the last one *UEFI Firmware Settings*. Am I not supposed to see the Windows entry listed? How would I then boot to Windows at next restart?

Here is the output from `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-54-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-54-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-53-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-53-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-52-generic (recovery mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use UEFI, you can make use of it's next-boot-feature.

All you need is the `efibootmgr`-command. Use

```
efibootmgr -v
```

to see the list of your boot entries. Then choose the entry for the next boot with

```
sudo efibootmgr -n XXXX
```

where `XXXX` is the number of the desired entry from the list.

```
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks! I see `BootOrder: 0001,0000 ` and `Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager` so `0000` will be the number, right? And also this is just for one reboot, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! My initial problem is that my laptop screen is broken and I don't see the GRUB menu. Setting `efibootmgr` to *Windows Boot Manager* still results into a black screen with nothing happening (as does choosing *Rescue and Recovery* or *Lenovo Diagnostics*), which could be due to the menu being shown but waiting for an input I can't see. Is there a more direct way to say I want to boot into the Windows first option? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's the same as if you would use the built in efi boot menu and choose Windows from there. Broken hardware should be repaired or replaced.