# Boot ignore GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to better understand dual boot but I have a problem.

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1. installed on the same PC (dual boot)

I want to set Ubuntu as default.

The boot default seems to be Windows but the problem is that I've tried to change the grub default to `GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"` from my Grub customizer but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: This might help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line  There is also the `grub-set-default` command to help set the default you want it to boot to.

Comment: If you use description, it must be the exact line that is in the grub menu. Copy & paste that. Normally ubuntu is first entry in grub and you just leave it at `GRUB_DEFAULT=0
` in /etc/default/grub. If you are looking at ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu, check this `sudo efibootmgr -v` and you can change boot order in UEFI with efibootmgr for many systems, HP (maybe some others) only allow changes from within UEFI. See `man efibootmgr` & http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr